# jqGrid Multi Column Search not working when columns selected right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have been working with jqgrid on a project and recently added the multi column search functionality when sorting by clicking on the column headers. Though this is working great when sorting columns left first then right, when you search the right column first then left, it is sending a request back to the server with the columns left first then right.

the cause seems to be around the code below but I can't see a work around for this. Can anyone help?

```
ts.p.sortorder = "";
            $.each(cm, function(i){
                if(this.lso) {
                    if(i>0 && fs) {
                        sort += ", ";
                    }
                    splas = this.lso.split("-");
                    sort += cm[i].index || cm[i].name;
                    sort += " "+splas[splas.length-1];
                    fs = true;
                    ts.p.sortorder = splas[splas.length-1];
                }
            });
            ls = sort.lastIndexOf(ts.p.sortorder);
            sort = sort.substring(0, ls);
            ts.p.sortname = sort;
ts.p.sortname = sort;
```

`ts.p.sortname = sort;` **this is always will be Left columm asc/desc, Right column asc/desc No matter if you have sort order with `Field2(right col)`, `Field1(left col)`**

Comment: I had this issue and I worked around it by moving the sort functionality over to the PHP side and essentially re-requesting the data and sorting on PHP every time I wanted a new sort executed. My coworkers solved this by switching to Slick Grid.